# Is asymptotic unbiasedness is a necessary condition for consistency: counter-example

Tags: measure-theory, statistics, expected-value, weak-convergence, parameter-estimation

> Suppose $T_n$ is a sequence of estimators of $\theta$ and suppose $ET_n\nrightarrow\theta$. Is is true that $T_n$ is NOT consistent for $\theta$?

I don't think unbiasedness is a necessary condition for consistency or, convergence in probability. But, I can't figure a counterexample to support my claim. Any help?

Comment: Regarding the title, you probably mean asymptotic unbiasedness. For a counterexample, take any consistent estimator $\hat\theta_n$ of $\theta$ from a parametric model and define $T_n$ such that $T_n=\hat\theta_n$ with high probability (i.e. probability tending to $1$) and $T_n=c_n$ otherwise, where $c_n$ is chosen in a way that ensures $E(T_n)$ does not converge to $\theta$.